# Why my save time function doesn't work? PHP + AJAX JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm working on a code that allow me to save in my database the time that a user spend on viewing a page, when he clicks on "Close" button, through AJAX i post on a php page some parameters to Insert into the DB (Mysql).

This is my code:

**window.php (the page that i'm viewing)**

```
<?php $start_time = microtime(true); 
?>

*page content*

<div align="center"><input type="button" value="Close" onclick="open()"></div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function open()
{
var start = <?php echo $start_time; ?>;
var end = <?php echo $end = microtime(true); ?>;
var uid = <?php echo $_SESSION['uid']; ?>;
var corso = <?php echo $_SESSION['cod']; ?>;
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.mysite.it/template/pages/save.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: "startt="+start+"&endt="+end+"&uid="+uid+"&corso="+corso,

  success: function(){ // trigger when request was successfull
     alert("Recorded!");
  },

})

}


</script>
```

And then my scriptpage in php:

**save.php**

```
<?php
require "connection.php";

$inizio = $_POST['startt'];
$fine = $_POST['endt'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$corso = $_POST['corso'];
$duration = $fine-$inizio;
$hours = (int)($duration/60/60);
$minutes = (int)($duration/60)-$hours*60;
$seconds = (int)$duration-$hours*60*60-$minutes*60;

$stringa = ($hours .":" .$minutes .":" .$seconds);
$sql = "INSERT INTO visua (utente, corso, tempo)
VALUES ($stringa, $uid, $corso)";
$result = $link->mysql_query($sql);
if ($result) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $link->error;
}

$link->close();

?>
```

Actually can't understand why don't work, even if the "success" part of AJAX display me the message, but no new lines on DB

Thank you in advice.

Comment: I really hope this is just an example... your data is not safe-- your code is very vulnerable to SQL injection right now!

Comment: i know but really can't find another way to do the same thing using more safe code :(

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function open()
{
  var start = '<?php echo $start_time; ?>';
  var end = '<?php echo $end = microtime(true); ?>';
  var uid = '<?php echo $_SESSION['uid']; ?>';
  var corso = '<?php echo $_SESSION['cod']; ?>';
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.mysite.it/template/pages/save.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: "startt="+start+"&endt="+end+"&uid="+uid+"&corso="+corso,

 success: function(){ // trigger when request was successfull
   alert("Recorded!");
},

})

}


</script>
```

Comment: Is it showing any error on console? don't forget to include `jquery`

Comment: Does jquery call happens or not? Exactly which portion is not working jquery call or Db insert? Try  `print_r($_POST)` on your save.php page if your jquery call is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php
require "connection.php";

$inizio = $_POST['startt'];
$fine = $_POST['endt'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$corso = $_POST['corso'];
$duration = $fine-$inizio;
$hours = (int)($duration/60/60);
$minutes = (int)($duration/60)-$hours*60;
$seconds = (int)$duration-$hours*60*60-$minutes*60;

$stringa = ($hours .":" .$minutes .":" .$seconds);
$sql = "INSERT INTO visua (utente, corso, tempo)
VALUES ('$stringa', '$uid', '$corso')";
$result = $link->mysql_query($sql);
if ($result) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $link->error;
}

$link->close();

?>
```

May be  it will work....before that you need to check the ajax values or passed or not..

Comment: did u checked the ajax values passed or not

Comment: if suppose passed means echo the $SQL variable and try to run directly on MySQL server if suppose that also working fine means check the connection file

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function open(){
    var start = '<?php echo $start_time; ?>';
    var end = '<?php echo $end = microtime(true); ?>';
    var uid = '<?php echo $_SESSION['uid']; ?>';
    var corso = '<?php echo $_SESSION['cod']; ?>';
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.mysite.it/template/pages/save.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            startt : start,
            endt : end,
            uid : uid,
            corso : corso
        },
        success: function(){ // trigger when request was successfull
            alert("Recorded!");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Also, a logical issue which could help you. If you need to calculate the end time when a user closes the page, please calculate the end time in **save.php** file as,

```
<?php
$fine = microtime(true);

//Also try including single-quote in your query for insert
$sql = "INSERT INTO visua (utente, corso, tempo) VALUES ('$stringa', '$uid', '$corso')";
?>
```

This will give the expected result for you.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Also check your console if the post parameters are passed correctly.